# Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908) Mac High Sierra 10.13

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile, macos-high-sierra

I'm currently running vargant version 2.1.5 on my mac high sierra 10.13.6

So after completing the `vagrant init` and `vagrant up` command I'm suppose to have a fully running virtual machine in virtualbox. But after running vagrant up I get this instead.

There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "3574f45d-aade-4053-af8b-0c88330e855f", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'saltstates_default_1539870640620_6152' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine

Any idea what this is about?

Comment: DId you solve this issue yet? And how? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

So if you have mac high sierra or higher, mac security and system preferences allow applications to make system changes with in a 30 mins of installation of the application. So I had to uninstall virtual box then reinstall it. Then I went to system preferences and allow kernel driver changes.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to reinstall VirtualBox in order to resolve this problem. As described in the [VirtualBox forum for macOS hosts](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=84778&start=15#p412500), you can do the following instead:

1. Restart your machine and enter Recovery Mode (Press and hold <kbd>⌘-R</kbd> on reboot.)
2. Open the Terminal.
3. Type the following: `spctl kext-consent add VB5E2TV963`
4. Press  <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Restart your machine.

Answer (score 0):

When you install application, on Mac OS, you have to accept permission.

Follow the step.

[image: In system preferences go to security & privacy]

After: [image: Now click to allow permissions]